# http request fails due to json size - response 503 and Heroku error H13

Tags: json, heroku, gunicorn, http-status-code-503, http-post

I have a simple flask application running on heroku:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return 'OK'
```

Incredibly it succeeds or fails, depending on the size of the json I send. Here's the test code:

```
import json, random, string, requests

def rand_string(size):
    return ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(size)])

for size in (4000, 10000):
    r = requests.post('http://my-app.herokuapp.com/test',
                      data=json.dumps(rand_string(size)),
                      headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
    print r.status_code
```

On the first call it returns status 200, on the second http status 503 with a H13 heroku error code.

```
2014-09-18T08:23:46.594543+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/test" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=91b1cd91-5a4f-445e-ad52-3c64733154b3 fwd="12.34.56.78" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=13ms status=503 bytes=0
```

[HTTP response 503](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) means:

> server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary
>   overloading or maintenance of the server

This couldn't be the case, as the server is up and running and has no load except for my manual tests.

Heroku's [H13 code documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response) says:

> This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a
>   connection, but then closes the socket without writing anything to it.

However all the code does is `return 'OK'` so it ain't the code.

Does heroku limit the size of requests? Does gunicorn?
How can I find out and how do I configure it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

You may have been affected by gunicorn's timeout mechanism, which defaults to 30s. If serializing for some reason takes longer than that, the worker is killed and restarted.